# Why cant the compiler resolve the resulting type?

Tags: c#

I have two `IEnumerable`s of different types, both of which derive from a common base class. Now I try to union the enumerables to get an enumerable of the base class. I have to explicitly cast one of the enumerables to the base class for this to work.

I would have guessed that the Compiler would have automatically chosen the closest common base type for the resulting enumerable, but it does not.

Here is an example of that behavior:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class BaseClass { }
    public class DerivedClass1 : BaseClass { }
    public class DerivedClass2 : BaseClass { }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<DerivedClass1> list1 = new List<DerivedClass1>();
            List<DerivedClass2> list2 = new List<DerivedClass2>();
            var a = list1.Union(list2); // Compiler Error
            IEnumerable<BaseClass> b = list1.Union(list2); // Compiler Error
            var c = list1.Cast<BaseClass>().Union(list2); // This works
            var d = list1.Union(list2.Cast<BaseClass>()); // This works
            var e = list1.Cast<BaseClass>().Union(list2.Cast<BaseClass>()); // This works, but ReSharper wants to remove one of the casts
        }
    }
}
```

`var c` seems to be easy to explain, as the first enumerable is now of type `BaseClass`, so a union with the second list, which contains elements which are derived from BaseClass also is easy to understand.

`var d`is not so easy to understand for me, because we start with an enumerable of `DerivedClass1` and union that with `BaseClass` elements. I am surprised that this works. Is it because a union operation is kind of an commutative operation and so it has to work as `c` also works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's worth remembering that `Union` is an extension method. Here's the method signature you're calling:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Union<TSource> (
    this IEnumerable<TSource> first, 
    IEnumerable<TSource> second);
```

So your calls are effectively:

```
var a = Enumerable.Union(list1, list2);
IEnumerable<BaseClass> b = Enumerable.Union(list1, list2); 
var c = Enumerable.Union(list1.Cast<BaseClass>(), list2);
var d = Enumerable.Union(list1, list2.Cast<BaseClass>());
var e = Enumerable.Union(list1.Cast<BaseClass>(), list2.Cast<BaseClass>());
```

The argument types involved in those calls are:

```
a: List<DerivedClass1>, List<DerivedClass2>
b: List<DerivedClass1>, List<DerivedClass2> // Variable being assigned to doesn't matter
c: IEnumerable<BaseClass>, List<DerivedClass2>
d: List<DerivedClass1>, IEnumerable<BaseClass>
e: IEnumerable<BaseClass>, IEnumerable<BaseClass>
```

There are clearly three categories here:

- `a` and `b` are the same. We'll look at that later.
- `c` and `d` are mirror images of each other. Note how it doesn't matter which is used as the `this` parameter, as far as type inference is involved. More later...
- `e` is simple: `T` is inferred as `BaseClass` in a really obvious way

Now `a` and `b` don't work because `BaseClass` never exists as a candidate type. From what I remember of the type inference algorithm (and it really is *very* complicated), a type will never be inferred as a type argument when that type isn't present in any of the argument types. So while both `BaseClass` and `object` would be *valid* explicit generic type arguments, neither of those will be inferred.

`c` and `d` resolve to `T` being `BaseClass`, because there are inferences that require that there's a conversion from `IEnumerable<BaseClass>` to `IEnumerable<T>`, and that there's a conversion from `List<DerivedClass2>` or `List<DerivedClass1>` (respectively for `c` and `d`) to `IEnumerable<T>`. That's only true for `T=BaseClass` out of the types being considered, so that's what's inferred.

Comment: Great explanation as always! I'm curious what happens when `var a = list1.Union<BaseClass>(list2);` as well?

Comment: @S.Akbari: Well, at that point there's no type inference involved, because the type argument is provided explicitly. It works because both `List<DerivedClass1>` and `List<DerivedClass2>` are implicitly convertible to `IEnumerable<BaseClass>`. I won't add this to the answer as the question is about type inference.

Answer (score 4):

> Why cant the compiler resolve the resulting type?

That question is based on a false belief; that the compiler is unable to  figure out a common type. The compiler could figure that out quite easily, it simply chooses not to, and there is a good reason it for it.

When the compiler reasons about this, it will always use the types involved in the expression. If not, then where should it stop? Everything could be reduced to `IEnumerable<object>` and make it work, but that would probably be masking an unintended behavior and probably a bug:

```
//ee is implicitly typed as IEnumerable<object>
var ee = someEnumerableOfString.Union(someEnumerableOfFoo);
```

A similar thing happens with the `?` operator. The compiler wont go looking for a common ancestor, be it a common base type, an interface or a simply object.

And its a good feature because its not always clear what commonality you would want. Imagine the following:

```
class A: IBar { }
class B: A, IFoo
class C: A, IFoo

var aa = someEnumerableOfB.Union(someEnumerableOfC);
```

Why should `aa` be of type `IEnumerable<A>`? Why not `IEnumerable<IFoo>`? And why not `IEnumerable<IBar>`? It could go on forever...

Another important factor to consider, and that could be leading to confusion is, in the following hypothetically legal statement:

```
IEnumerable<A> aa = someEnumerableOfB.Union(someEnumerableOfC);
```

One could argue that you are explicitly specifying the commonality you want with `IEnumerable<A>`.

But that is not how the compiler reasons out types; the compiler will not try to figure out the type of the righthand side based on the type information of the left hand side of the assignment. The way it works is that it will try to figure out the type of the right hand side and if succeeds, *then* it will see if its assignable to the left hand side. The error you are getting is because it fails in the first step.

Answer (score 3):

It cant union DerivedClass2 with DerivedClass1, they share a base class but they are not the same type by any means

```
var c = list1.Cast<BaseClass>().Union(list2); // This works
```

this will work since now the union is between BaseClass and  DerivedClass2  and DerivedClass2   can be converted into BaseClass since baseClass.GetType().IsAssigneableFrom(derivedClass2)

Answer (score 2):

You basically have `D1 : B` and `D2 : B`.

The union of `IEnumerable<D1>` (or `IEnumerable<D2>`) and `IEnumerable<B>` is an instance of `IEnumerable<B>` (the order being irrelevant).

It's also sound to say that a union of `IEnumerable<D1>` and `IEnumerable<D2>` is an instance of `IEnumerable<B>`. But in this case, the compiler needs to find the common ancestor of `D1` and `D2`, which apparently doesn't bother to do.